# CORS problem when the NestJs backend redirects to facebook

Tags: angular, facebook, oauth-2.0, cors, nestjs

I'm trying to integrate authentication via facebook/goole into my application, when I run the endpoint directly on the browser it redirects fine, but when I call it from the front (Angular) I got this cors error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMlHh.png)
However, I did activate the cors on main.ts
`app.enableCors(); app.enableCors({ origin: ['http://localhost:4200'], credentials: true, });`
did I miss something?

i tried to activate CORS by `app.enableCors(); app.enableCors({ origin: ['http://localhost:4200'], credentials: true, });`
the other APIS works fine but the redirection to Facebook does not work

Comment: CORS settings won't help you here. You can not request the Facebook login URL _in the background_ - you need to _directly_ send the user there.